# How to open a file with the extension .msr?

Tags: file-extension

I'm trying to open a file with the extension .msr. I've really tried to find a program to open this kind of file, but unfortunately I can't find something. It is a measure file which should show a diagram depending on measured data.
I would be glad if someone could help me.

Thank you,

Ordo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's this: http://bersoft.com/bimagem/help/export_options.htm

> **MSR file:**
>   Saves the data as a Bersoft Image measurement file with .MSR file extension. This is the same format used to save measurements along the images.

That help page is for the following software: http://bersoft.com/bimagem/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I can't open my files with the software.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. I can open the files with PHYWE - Measure.